# GoDaddy SSL on Shared Hosting

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, godaddy

So I'm very new to using SSL certificates and I have been trying to install one on a site for a client. He is using shared hosting for multiple domains through GoDaddy, and the site we're working on is **not** the primary domain.

He purchased a UCC certificate for multiple domains and I installed it on the shared hosting account. My thought was that since the domains were under the same hosting account, then they would each be protected under the certificate. This was not the case...apparently.

I checked both domains with an SSL checker and the primary domain checked out. The domain that we **wanted** the SSL on showed the following errors:

```
None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered 
(www.CLIENTDOMAIN.com). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a
web browser.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. It was just purchased yesterday, so if necessary, I guess I could un-install it or re-key it (???). Is there a way to just change the common name to www.CLIENTDOMAIN.com (the correct domain)?

Comment: It looks like the certificate wasn't actually a certificate for multiple domains. Did the CA verify each domain you want the certificate to work for? Did you actually look at the certificate to check its common names or alternate names?

Comment: When I was installing it, I remember there being a dropdown for me to select the domain that I want to install the SSL on, but the only one I saw was the primary domain, so I figured that's how it worked with shared hosting.

Comment: I'm not talking about installing, I'm talking about the certificate *itself*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to add another SAN (subject alternative name) with the correct domain. Once submitted, it deleted the old certificate and installed the new one with both URLs on it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to buy a new SSL certificate for the right domain (common name), as you cannot just change it as you want.

Comment: Drat. That was what I was afraid of. Hopefully they can process a refund or transfer it to the correct domain. Thanks.

Comment: Where I buy my SSL certificates, there is a up to two weeks refund period - so it shouldn't be that much of an issue.